# Day difference in Django annotation

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to do something equivalent to the following:

```
MyModel.objects.all().annotate(
      days_since_start = ExpressionWrapper(
          (F(date) - start_date).days, 
          output_field=IntegerField()
      )
)
```

Of course, this won't work, as `F(date) - start_date` ends up as SQL, and `.days` does not work as it requires a timedelta object.

Is this annotation possible some other way? I'd rather not pull all the data out of the database and calculate this value row by row.

Comment: A time difference function depends much on the database backend and probably all methods as_sqlite, as_mysql, as_postgres... must me implemented separately. What is the most important backend?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this solution on Postgres:

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(
    day_diff=Extract(
        timezone.now() - F("start_date"),
        lookup_name="epoch",
    )
    / 86400
)
```

Since we find the difference in seconds, it is also possible to find all kind of differences such as hours, weeks, months etc.

Extract casts int to the result, however you can set `output_field` to `FloatField` to get extra precision e.g., 1.7 days instead of 2